# Python: Obtain the row number of a CSV file which has the minimum Euclidean distance from a point

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, math

I have a [CSV file](https://github.com/sunnysinghnitb/datasets/blob/master/fuel_veg_cover.csv) with columns R, G, B. These three columns represent [X, Y, Z] coordinates of a point in space. I, also, have a point A with coordinates: [78, 95, 44].

What I want to achieve is to calculate the Euclidean distance of this point A from every point (formed by columns R, G, B) on the CSV file. After calculating all distances, I want to obtain the row number of file which has the minimum Euclidean distance.

The following code calculates Euclidean distance between two points:

```
import math
p1 = [4, 0, 9]
p2 = [6, 6, 3]
distance = math.sqrt( ((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2)+((p1[2]-p2[2])**2) )

print(distance)
```

How can I achieve this using Python?

Comment: This is not a place for other people to do your homework....

Comment: This is not a homework problem. I'm trying to achieve something more complex. I've only shared the part where I got stuck.

Comment: First hint: finding the point with lowest distance is equivalent to finding the point with lowest **squared** distance, so you can remove `math.sqrt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go (at the end the first row is the minimum distance):

```
import pandas as pd
import math

def calc_distance(x):
    A = [4, 0, 9] # replace this with your A values
    return math.sqrt(((A[0]-x['R'])**2)+((A[1]-x['G'])**2)+((A[2]-x['B'])**2))

    df = pd.read_csv('fuel_veg_cover.csv')
   df['distance'] = df.apply(calc_distance, axis=1)
   df = df.sort_values(by=['distance'])
   df
```

Comment: The call to `math.sqrt` is not needed.

Comment: Yep. Used what divkrsh wrote

Comment: You could also use `df.idxmin()` instead of `df.sort_values`, if all OP's interested in is the closest point.